# Code::Blocks returns -10737741819 (0xC0000005) when executing MySQL loop insert c++

Tags: c++, mysql

I've been making program that need to continuously insert data to a database. I'm new to C++.
I'm using xampp for my database. I want to make insert loop inside one of my function.
my code looks like this

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "fstream"
#include "iostream"
#include "mysql.h"
#include "sstream"

void loop();
void print();

int i;
const char* hostname    = "localhost";
const char* username    = "root";
const char* password    = "";
const char* database    = "testinsertdb";
unsigned int port       = 3306;
const char* unixsocket  = NULL;
unsigned long clientflag = 0;


insertion(){
    MYSQL* conn;
    conn = mysql_init(0);
    conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, hostname, username, password, database, port, unixsocket, clientflag);
    int qstate=0;
    using namespace std;
    stringstream ss;
        ss << " INSERT INTO test (number) values ('" <<i<<"')";
        string query = ss.str ();
        const char * q = query.c_str();
        qstate = mysql_query(conn, q);
         if (qstate == 0)
        {

            cout <<" Record inserted successfully ..."<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout <<" Error, data not inserted..."<<endl;
        }
}

int main()
{
    print();
    return 0;
}

void print()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
     loop();
}
}


void loop()
{
    i=1;
    insertion();
}
```

When I run the program, I managed to insert some data to the database, but after several seconds the program stopped with code `-10737741819 (0xC0000005)`.  On my build log Process the terminated with status `-1073741510`
How can i solve this?

Comment: You're leaking memory like a sieve, making a million connections to the database. You should init and connect *once*, and you should clean up after yourself.

Comment: Connect once (when your program starts) instead of connecting every time you want to make an insertion. And don't forget to close the connection when your program exits. Beside the point but using function parameters instead of global variables wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: How many connections to one database can you make?

Comment: @john thank you for the advice, it's working now, i make the MySQL* conn into global variable

Comment: @PepijnKramer i'm not sure about this sir, i'm still new and learning.

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you for the advice sir, i'll keep it in mind, it's just that i need this program to be done as fast as possible now. I'll keep learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferablly try this one.

Your code is trying to connect database as many times as the loop proceeds.

There is the description of that error from this [link](https://astera.ru/how-to/windows-10/oshibka-0xc0000005/)

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "fstream"
#include "iostream"
#include "mysql.h"
#include "sstream"

void loop();
void print();

MYSQL* conn;

const char* hostname    = "localhost";
const char* username    = "root";
const char* password    = "";
const char* database    = "testinsertdb";
unsigned int port       = 3306;
const char* unixsocket  = NULL;
unsigned long clientflag = 0;


void insertion() {
    int qstate=0, i;
    using namespace std;
    stringstream ss;
    
    ss << " INSERT INTO test (number) values ('" <<i<<"')";
    string query = ss.str ();
    const char * q = query.c_str();
    qstate = mysql_query(conn, q);

    if (qstate == 0)
    {

        cout <<" Record inserted successfully ..."<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout <<" Error, data not inserted..."<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    print();
    return 0;
}

void print()
{
    conn = mysql_init(0);
    conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, hostname, username, password, database, port, unixsocket, clientflag);

    for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
     loop();

    mysql_close(conn);     
}



void loop()
{
    i=1;
    insertion();
}
```

Comment: thank you sir, it's working now. But i put the connection inside main() but still works fine.

Comment: That's great. Yep. It's nice to help you.

Comment: And, also for this process, you should close the database connection after running all necessary tasks for database.